# Discovering exchange rate based on the rates of others

Tags: education

i'm trying to convert one currency to another, based on what that currency rate is to USD.

If `1 USD is 1.350297NZD`, what is `1NZD to GBP` if `1 USD is 0.70632 GBP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common thread is $1$ USD. So
\begin{align}
1\, \text{USD} &= 1.350297 \,\text{NZD} \\
             &= 0.70632 \,\text{GBP} \\
\implies 1 \,\text{NZD} &= \left(\frac{0.70632}{1.350297}\right)\, \text{GBP} \\
&= 0.523085\, \text{GBP}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use unit cancellation. Then you don't have to remember when to multiply, when to divide. You want
$$
\frac{? \text{ NZD}}{1 \text{ GBP}}
= 
\frac{1.3... \text{ NZD}}{1 \text{ USD}} \times
\frac{1\text{ USD}}{0.7... \text{GBP}}.
$$
Then do the arithmetic. Invert if you want the other conversion.